# Passing taxonomy id of taxonomy clicked on one page to another page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, urls, site-url, pods-framework

I'm a beginner, and not very well versed with Wordpress.

This is my setup - I have plugins Pods Admin (for custom post types and custom taxonomies), and Page Builder by SiteOrigin (for creating my wordpress pages).

I have a custom post type called 'documents'. This has a custom taxonomy attached to it called 'products'.

What I am trying to achieve is, have a page with a list of products, and on clicking on a product, see the related documents.

I am struggling with knowing which product the user has clicked on (on page 1) to show the relevant documents (on page 2).

I have gotten as far as having the term ID of the clicked product on the URL of page 2. e.g. www.example.com/documents-page/56 i.e. 56 being the term id of the clicked product on page 1. How do I read the URL of page 2?

Or, is there any simpler way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Your **list of products** is a list of taxonomy terms.

You can get this list with those functions:

`get_terms($args)` — Retrieve the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.
`get_the_terms($post, $taxonomy)` — Retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

**Clicking on a Product** — is opening a custom taxonomy archive page.

See [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) for details.